# Excluding specific data from sql when field entry begins with #

Tags: mysql

I need to modify this sql query

```
"SELECT 
    c.categories_id,
    categories_name
FROM 
    " . TABLE_CATEGORIES ." c, 
    " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd  
WHERE c.categories_id  = cd.categories_id 
AND parent_id=" . App_DefaultCategoryID . " 
AND categories_status=1 
AND cd.language_id = " . $language_id . " 
ORDER BY sort_order, categories_name ";
```

so that it does not include results where the categories_name field contains any data beginning with a #, for instance #Curiosities.

How can i exclude such data from the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using a `NOT LIKE` statement, i.e. by adding the following to the WHERE criteria

`AND categories_name NOT LIKE '#%'`

As an addition, it may be an idea to add the table prefix to all field names for clarity later on.  I don't know which tables each column comes from though so you're on your own on that.